# How to write straight to disk in c

Tags: c, ubuntu, filesystems

So I am trying to make a program that will wipe drives. After some research I found that all devices are stored under the /dev/ folder in Ubuntu. I tried the following...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/sdb1", "w");
    fwrite("\0", 1, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

But found that it returned

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why is this? Should I not be able just to write to the disk?

Comment: I wouldn't do it at your current level of understanding (no offence intended, just warning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely don't have permissions to open `/dev/sdb1`. Check the result of `fopen` (`fp`) before you try to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/sdb1", "w");
    if(fp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening /dev/sdb1: %s\n", 
                strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    /* Now you can use fp */
    fwrite(0, 1, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

[`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) returns `NULL` when opening failed, and puts the reason in the global* variable [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) returns a descriptive string for that error code.

You'll probably need to run your program as root to access the block devices. Needless to say, debug it very well before doing so, or you might ruin your system (especially if you're messing about with direct disk access).